# Optimal Solution for a computation problem

Tags: python

Here is the question --->

[image]

The inputs are 2 6 10.
The output should be 41.

Here is the explanation to the Output:

[image]

My code give the correct output but gets slower as numbers get larger. My code is below.

```
def findMinGameCycle(e, n, m_0):
    r_total=2**(n-1)*(e+1)
    rest=0
    cycle=n
    m_total=m_0
    while m_total<=r_total:
        rest+=1
        cycle+=rest+1
        m_0+=1
        m_total+=m_0
    return cycle
```

Comment: Could you provide a short description of the problem in the body of your question?  Some people can't read/access image links.

Comment: if you want to improve already working code -- you should probably try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Scientific computing 101: first, try to throw math at the problem.  This problem has a closed form solution, and it just requires looking at the patterns and the quadratic formula.

Let `e, n, m_0` as above.

At cycle 0, there are `e+1` enemies.  At cycle 1, there are `2(e+1)`.  At cycle 2, there are `4(e+1)`.  Extrapolating, it seems that at cycle `n-1` (where they stop replicating), there are `2^(n-1)(e+1)` enemies.

At cycle n, there are `m_0` minions.  At cycle `n+2` (he had to wait a turn), there are `m_0 + (m_0 + 1)`.  At cycle `n+5` (he had to wait two turns), there are `m_0 + (m_0+1) + (m_0+2)`.  Rearranging, at cycle `n+5` there are `3m_0 + (1+2)` minions.  At cycle `n+9` there are `4m_0 + (1+2+3)` minions, and at cycle `n+14` there are `5m_0 + (1+2+3+4)` minions.  Extrapolating, at cycle `n+k(k+1)/2-1` (see the link below), there are `km_0 + (1+2+3+....(k-1))` minions.  The sum on the right is [equal to `k(k-1)/2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

We want to know when the minions outnumber the enemies.  If the numbers were continuous, then the moment when one overtakes the other, they are equal.

I.e. `2^(n-1)(e+1) == km_0 + k(k-1)/2`

This is a quadratic equation in `k` (recall that `n,m_0,e` are fixed and given).

Solving for `k` using the handy [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) We get:

`k = (1/2-m0) + sqrt((m0-1/2)^2+2^n*(e+1))`

Note that in our problem, `k` is NOT continuous, however, so we must make it integral at this point.  If `k` is a fraction, we must round up to the next integer, since at the next integer down, there are not enough minions.

Once we round `k`, we can use it to find the cycle, which was given by the formula `n+k(k+1)/2-1` above.

Here is all of this logic in python:

```
import math

def turns(e,n,m0):
    k = (1/2-m0) + ((m0-1/2)**2+2**n*(e+1))**0.5
    k = math.ceil(k)
    return n + k*(k+1)/2 - 1

>>> turns(2,6,10)
41.0
```

Since we took the time to do some math, there are no loops, and we have a constant time solution.

Comment: If you like this sort of problem, check out [project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/)

Comment: Your code works fine bt gives incorrect answer for certain test cases

Comment: I have tested it for a couple of different inputs.  Do you have an example of such a failing test case?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/uwi-comp2211-2019-potw-01/challenges/league-of-legions there is where the test cases run